# Entity Framework combine lambda expressions from different entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, entity-framework-6, expression

I have 2 lambda expressions that are virtually the same. One returns `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>` and the other returns `Expression<Func<Admission, bool>>`.

There is a direct relationship between these 2 entities. A `Person` can have many `Admissions`.

The two expressions look like this:

**Person** expression:

```
public static Expression<Func<Person, bool>> SearchPerson(string searchTerm)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
    {
        return p => true;
    }

    return p => p.Nhino.Contains(searchTerm) || 
                p.Firstname.Contains(searchTerm) || 
                p.Lastname.Contains(searchTerm) || 
                p.Pfname.Contains(searchTerm);
}
```

**Admission** expression:

```
public static Expression<Func<Admission, bool>> SearchPerson(string searchTerm)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
    {
        return a => true;
    }

    return a => a.Person.Nhino.Contains(searchTerm) || 
                a.Person.Firstname.Contains(searchTerm) || 
                a.Person.Lastname.Contains(searchTerm) || 
                a.Person.Pfname.Contains(searchTerm);
}
```

These search expressions are used extensively throughout the system.

Notice that the `return` statements are virtually identical, and if our client wants to add more search criteria to the list I want to have this logic in one place and not have to update it for both the `Admission` and `Person` expressions.

Is there a way to create an expression or similar that can be used in both the `People.Where()` clause and the `Admissions.Where()` clause (or even other Parent/Child relationships that want to search by the same `Person` criteria) without duplicating code?

Comment: Looks like you are seeking for a way to compose expressions. You can take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782110/linq-to-entities-use-func-to-create-property-in-a-select-statement-that-produc/43784673#43784673).

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have control over the design of these classes, you can implement an interface with a predicate function.

For example:

```cs
public interface ITestable
{
    Func<string, bool> Predicate { get; }
}

public class Admission : ITestable
{
    // ...other members...

    public Person Person { get; }

    public Expression<Func<string, bool>> Predicate =>
        x => Person.Predicate(x);
}

public class Person : ITestable
{
    // ...other members...

    public Expression<Func<string, bool>> Predicate =>
        x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) || FirstName.Contains(x) || LastName.Contains(x);
}

// The calling code:
IQueryable<ITestable> people =
    source.Where(x => x.Predicate(searchTerm));
```

Comment: Not bad ... but it seems that I would still have the where clauses in both classes. Ideally I would like to have the '.Contains()' in only the Person class... Is this possible?

Comment: @Gwasshoppa You could delegate the `Admission.Predicate` function to the `Person.Predicate`. Then you only need to maintain the `Contains` calls in one place

Comment: Very nice... Ill whack it into my code and up vote if it works as good as it looks :)

Comment: One question: how do I then call this in my `Admissions.Where()`... Do I need a `SearchPerson()` in both the `Admission` & `Person` models? The `Admission` Model would obviously have to return `Expression<Func<Admission, bool>>` rather than `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>` or could I make the Type generic somehow?

Comment: Ok... So i have implemented your suggestion but now I am getting an error. 

"The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."

Comment: Are you trying to call this method inside of a lambda on an `IQueryable<T>`?

Comment: The `Invoke` error is related to EF trying to execute a `Func`. Replace the `Func` properties with expressions. I've edited the example. Further, you could skip the static method altogether and just access the property.

Comment: Thanks will try that over the weekend :)... will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the update... I have tried your suggestion by changing the 

    `public Func<string, bool> Predicate => x => Person.Predicate(x)` 

to an Expression

    `public Expression<Func<string, bool>> Predicate => x => Person.Predicate(x);`

but unfortunately this gives me a compile error "Non-invocable member 'Person.Predicate' cannot be used like a method."

Do you have any further suggestions?